# Intellij renames project when adding new modules

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project that I occasionally have to add/remove modules from (adding via the File > New > Module... option). However, each time I add a module, the project name changes to the name of the new module, and it's annoying to have to manually change it back. Is there a way to prevent renaming on module addition?